# probability using cards and envelopes

Tags: probability

You have 26 cards and 7 envelopes (labeled 1,2, ..,7). 
In how many ways can you put the 26 cards into the envelopes if

a. The cards are distinct?
b. The cards are identical? 
c. The cards are identical and no envelope can be left empty?